# Where to place air, water and electric cables in a composite beam

Tags: design, beam, structures, concrete

If water, gas and electrical cables have to pass through three (3) openings
provided in the cross section shown in Figure 2, with tangible and scientific
arguments specify the adequate opening for water, for gas and for electrical
cables.
[image: Composite beam]

Comment: What are your arguments on this matter? Please [edit] them into the question.

Comment: This seems like  homework to me. @Bernard please show what you've tried.

Comment: Without the specs for how much and at what pressure/voltage the three items carry, you're just guessing.    Frankly, if the pipes and wires fit, who would care how they're routed, unless the electric run has specs for airspace?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

For safety reasons, the gas line shall be placed in the highest void (3), then the electrical cable in the void (2). The water pipe shall be placed in the bottom void (1).

The above arrangement is based on the thinking of - gas must not below the live electric line, for which could ignite, and live electrical line must not below the water pipe, which could leak.

In reality, this is an ill-advised/problematic application, to place all three utilities in a narrow confined space (beam, trench), that will not permit by the applicable code.

Answer (score 0):

All utility lines have to be exposed, marked, accessible for maintenance.

Each has its own code of the proper location, protection from accident or intentional damage.

They have codes for repair crew set up of the work area, securing the site, providing a safe bypass for traffic or people passing by.

Inside a composite beam is not a practical place for utility lines unless the beam section is large enough to allow access and space for work, and meets the requirements for each utility line like electrical tray insulation and access, etc.

Comment: this could be in a factory, which would have none of these requirements unless by the insurance company.

Comment: especially in a plant. safety and security and immediate access is unavoidable.